# Graph Fourier transform definition

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I have a question about the definition of the graph Fourier transform. Let me start with definition.

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ with vertex set $V = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. The Laplacian matrix of $G$ is defined as $L = D - A$, where $D$ is a diagonal degree matrix with $d_{ii} = deg(i)$. Let $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_n$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $L$ and $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ be the corresponding eigenvalues. Let $f$ be a $V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function. The graph Fourier transform is defined as
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(\lambda_i) = \langle f, \varphi_i \rangle = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_i^*(k)
\end{equation}

My question is: what happens if $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i + 1}$? It seems to me that this definition could give two different values for $\hat{f}(\lambda_i)$.
Is it guaranteed that $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_i^*(k) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_{i+1}^*(k)$?

EDIT:
I have no problem with choosing an orthonormal eigenbasis even if there are eigenvalues with multiplicity bigger than $1$. My problem arises only after the eigenvectors are chosen. Suppose that $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i + 1} = 3$. Then I have two different formulas for $\hat{f}(3)$:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(3) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_i^*(k) 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(3) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_{i+1}^*(k)
\end{equation}

I think there are two possibilities:

1. The two quantities above are the same:
   $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_i^*(k) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_{i+1}^*(k)$. I can't see why this would be true.
2. I misunderstand something about the definition.

Comment: when there are degenerate eigenvalues the eigenvectors are not uniquely defined; for $d$ identical eigenvalues you have a $d$-dimensional eigenspace and you are free to choose any $d$ independent vectors in that space as your basis.

Comment: I have no problem with choosing an orthonormal eigenbasis even if there are eigenvalues with multiplicity bigger than $1$. My problem arises only after the eigenvectors are chosen. If  $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i + 1} = 3$, then I have two different formulas for $\hat{f}(3)$. I've edited the question, hope it makes my problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the definition I mentioned in the question in many places. (E.g. [here](http://www.norbertwiener.umd.edu/Research/lectures/2014/MBegue_Prelim.pdf).) In [Graph Structured Data Viewed Through a Fourier Lens](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/techreports/ucb/text/EECS-2013-209.pdf) the definition is different:
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(i) = <f, \varphi_i> = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n f(k) \varphi_i^*(k)
\end{equation}
This answers my question. :)